# Получение значений из связанных таблиц с условием

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы **countries** (имеет поле `name`) и **cities** (имеет поля `name` и `population`). Нужно получить все страны вместе с их городами, численность населения которых больше, например, 100.

В файле модели `Country` прописана связь:

```
public function cities()
{
  return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

В файле контроллера `CountryController` пытаюсь получить все записи с применением условия:

```
$countries = Country::all()
  ->cities()
  ->where('population', '>', 100);
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::city does not exist.
```

p.s. Если получать по **id** каждую отдельную запись через `find($id)`, то всё работает. Однако, всё, что возвращает несколько записей, будь то `all()` или `find([$id])`, то результатом возвращается данная ошибка.

Comment: Пробовал получить все записи через метод all() и потом делал перебор через foreach, но в результате получил зависшую страницу из рода бесконечного цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если надо получить города с населением больше 100.

```
$countries = Country::with(['cities' => function($city) {
    $city->where('population', '>', 100);
  }])
  ->get();
```

2. Если надо получить страны, в которых есть города с населением больше 100.

```
$countries = Country::with('cities')
  ->whereHas('cities', function ($city) {
    $city->where('population', '>', 100);
  })
  ->get();
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужно делать сперва запрос на получение всех стран, в которых есть города с населением больше 100, и отправлять во view, а потом еще и отдельно получить сами города, чтобы вывести их численность? Вместе никак?

Comment: @ЛеонидЕлкин Вы получаете уже все эти данные из запросов, предоставленных в ответе. У страны будет массив `cities`, где будет информация о городах. Дополнительных запросов делать не нужно.

Comment: @ЛеонидЕлкин В то время как конструкциями типа `Country::all()->cities()` Вы заставляете систему дополнительно делать запросы без оптимизации, и такой запрос может делаться на каждую строку из полученной коллекции.

Comment: @ЛеонидЕлкин В моём ответе в первом варианте вы получите все страны, а также города в этих странах, в которых численность больше 100. Во втором же варианте вы получите только те страны, в которых есть города с численностью больше 100. Выбирайте, что вам нужно для конкретной задачи.

Comment: @AntonMironov Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Второй вариант подошел больше, но пришлось немного подогнать под мою задачу.